# Creating a dict out of a larger corpus

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, corpus

I have a corpus of 30000 messages.

```
corpus = [
    "hello world", 
    "i like mars", 
    "a planet called venus", 
    ... , 
    "it's all pcj500"]
```

I have tokenized them and formed a `word_set` that contains all unique words.

```
word_lists = [text.split(" ") for text in corpus]
>>> [['hello', 'world'],
    ['i', 'like', 'mars'],
    ['a', 'planet', 'called', 'venus'],
    ...,
    ["it's", 'all', 'pcj500']]

word_set = set().union(*word_lists)
>>> ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'like', ..., 'pcj500']
```

1. I am trying to create a list of dictionaries with `word in the word_set` as *keys* with initial *values* as `0` for the count.
2. And if a `word in word_set` appear in `word_list in word_lists`, the
   appropriate count as the *values*.

For step 1, I am doing it this way,

```
tmp = corpus[:10]
word_dicts = []
for i in range(len(tmp)):
    word_dicts.append(dict.fromkeys(list(word_set)[:30], 0))

word_dicts
>>> [{'hello': 0,
  'world': 0,
  'mars': 0,
  'venus': 0,
  'explore': 0,
  'space': 0}]
```

**Problem:**

How can I perform the `dict.fromkeys` operation for all the texts in the corpus against all the items in `word_set`? For the whole corpus, I am running out of memory. There should be a better way to do this, but I am not able to find it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `defaultdict` or `Counter` from `collections`, which use lazy keys. Example:

```
from collections import Counter

word_dicts = []
for words_list in word_lists:
    word_dicts.append(Counter(words_list))
```